# ASP.NET IsCrossPagePostBack is false on post

Tags: asp.net, cross-page-posting

Our CMS is using a custom IHttpHandler to render our pages.
When CrossPagePosting IsCrossPagePostBack is always false and i cant get the value of fields from PreviousPage

Comment: You always can read values that are POSTed, just refer to `Request.Form` or `Request.Params`. It could possibly be just not **that** ellegant, comparing to reading control values referred through `PreviousPage`.

Comment: PreviousPage is null or it have values?

Comment: The Request.Form is a posibility but due to render method the id of the control is uncontrollable.
PreviosPage is null